# Activity is NULL in fragment, but not always in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, null

The `this.getActivity()` is NULL in my fragment, and is called from the actual activity itself.  This doesnt always happens but how can I fix this?

```
sportButton.setBackgroundColor(ViewHelper.getColor(this.getActivity()));
```

**EventActivity.java**

```
eventsFragment.setUpEvents(getEventApplication());
```

**EventsFragment.java**

```
public void setUpEvents(Application application) {
      sportButton.setBackgroundColor(ViewHelper.getColor(this.getActivity()));
```

Comment: Probably the timing of calling makes it null. One of the gurantee that this activity will not be null is when the `onActivityCreated` is called. Also when the Fragment is detach from the Activity the Fragment may outlive for a bit but the `getActivity()` will be null.

Comment: Try changing `this.getActivity()` to `getActivity()`

Comment: Why would remove `this` work?

Comment: Because `this` is a Context. Which doesn't belong to a Fragment. But it does to its container Activity.

Answer (score 0):

> just remove `this` from `this.getActivity()` and if you `extends` your
>   `Activity` from `AppCompatActivity` then you have to cast it with same
>   like below

```
(AppCompatActivity) getActivity()
```

Answer (score 0):

If its fragment which runs inside a parent activity then in that case you can create a static Activity object in EventActivity and reference that in fragments instead of getActivity(), because its guaranteed to be available to the fragments.

EventActivity.class

```
protected Activity activity;

onResume()
{
    activity = this;
}
```

EventsFragment.class

```
sportButton.setBackgroundColor(ViewHelper.getColor(EventActivity.activity));
```

hope it helps